# Raspberry Pi : White/Blank screen with new shielded cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, cables, emc, shielding, ffc

I'm currently passing EMC tests at a test lab. For the purpose of the tests, I made a custom DSI cable for the official Raspberry Pi 7" screen with shield against EMI as the PCB of the official RPF screen is a big source of noise.

I've just received my custom made cable but I can't get an image on the screen with it. I've checked :

- Pinout : OK
- Continuity between Raspberry and screen : OK
- Shorts between pins on the cable : OK

But still the screen only shows a blank/white screen and nothing else. When I switch back to the standard cable, the screen works as expected.

Here's a picture of the standard cable (up) and my custom made cable (down) :

[image: Cables]

Do you have any idea why my cable is not working ? I'm thinking about reflection inside the shield. Because of the shield, my cable could be self-poisoning. But, to be honest, I don't really know what's happening.

EDIT : I've tried something new. I removed the shield completely and the cable works fine. I took another cable and removed the shield only partially (but removed all connections to GND) and the screen works but I have a lot of black lines on it (like during conducted EFT/Burst tests).

Comment: One reason could be that the differential impedance of the unshielded cable with 1mm pitch is approximately the required 100 ohm impedance in the required GSSG configuration, but shielded cable can have differential impedance as low as 30 ohms. But I can't be sure if this is the reason so I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: Another possibility is that the shield was connected to ground on both ends?

Comment: The shield was grounded on both end but removing connection on one end and then on both end didn't solve the issue. With the whole shield, I have a blank screen. After removing partially the shield, I can have a picture but with a lot of black lines appearing on the screen. The more I remove the shield, the less I have these black lines. These black lines are the same type I get during IEC61000-4-4 test (EFT/burst). If I remove completely the shield, it's perfect. I did also a shield manually with Laird conductive fabric tape, it works like a charm (but take a lot of time to do....).